# How do I find the Dark Stars in Little Stars for Little Wars 2.0

Tags: little-stars-for-little-wars-2.0

In **Little Stars for Little Wars 2.0** each "world" has 54 Crosses, 54 Void Crosses and 3 Dark Stars. However I can't find any information on even how to start attempting the 3 Dark Stars aside from the fact that they are "hidden" ... Is a way to tell at least what levels they are on?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In recent update 2.1.3 the way black stars are obtained is changed. 
You can now see an empty yellow star above level - this indicates that in this level you can discover a black star. When obtained, icon above the level changes to full yellow star.

The way you can achieve a black star is different now. You can see a rotating star icon with a line to a single unconquered star. The star is following the path very slowly and after it reaches the unconquered star, the black star is created. Make sure you or your enemy doesn't conquere the star - otherwise the "anomally" is lost and you have to play again

Answer (score 1):

Found Black Stars on
2-11, 2-13, 2-16 and 6-14, 7-7, 8-18 (extra levels). Don't know how.

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming you found the voided crosses, if you didn't you need to complete each mission with 3 crosses.  Then start a mission, in the upper menu, find the menu the menu that enables "Difficult Mode".  The game color will change to purple and then winning levels will complete the void crosses.

As for the dark stars, I haven't found them yet.  I messaged Maxim (the game creator) but he hasn't given any hints.  I remember awhile ago, one of the game updates "fixed" hidden paths to stars that were not shown.  I am assuming it's something like this but to starts not shown on the map.

Answer (score 0):

I've found two of the nine Dark Stars so far. I'm not sure exactly how or why. I wonder if it's related to completing missions in order or some other criteria, but the two stars I located were in sectors 2-11 and 2-13. However the stars don't reliably reappear when I redo those sectors. It's also worth noting I only managed 2 crosses on 2-13 but I did manage 3 on 2-11. I haven't tried either on Hard mode yet.

Comment: This should be a comment, not an answer. Guesses aren't real answers. And since you're searching for a real answer, you shouldn't write a guess that pretends to be an answer.

Answer (score 0):

When you have one last un-conquered star left, wait a moment before sending all your ships to it. Instead look around and see if there's a dark circle around the map.

The key is the first sentence: One last star before you win the game.

Comment: Do they show up on specific maps, or is it random?

Comment: @aslum Only specific maps. I have tested 2-11 and 2-13 where there is a black star as your answer says, and some other maps where there isn't.